# ISTIO MIXER ADAPTER - Cannot make OPA adapter to work with the simplest example

Tags: istio, open-policy-agent

I am trying to setup the OPA adapter in Istio with the simplest rule to deny everything by default:

```
---
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: authorization
metadata:
  name: authz-instance
  namespace: istio-demo
spec:
  subject:
    user: source.uid | ""
  action:
    namespace: destination.namespace | "default"
    service: destination.service | ""
    method: request.method | ""
    path: request.path | ""

---
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: opa
metadata:
  name: opa-handler
  namespace: istio-demo
spec:
  policy:
    - |+
      package mixerauthz

      default allow = false
  checkMethod: "data.mixerauthz.allow"
  failClose: true

---
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: authz-rule
  namespace: istio-demo
spec:
  match: "true"
  actions:
  - handler: opa-handler.opa.istio-demo
    instances:
    - authz-instance.authorization.istio-demo
```

When I apply it, Istio's policy complains about not finding the `handler`:

```
istio-system/istio-policy-7f86484668-fc8lv[mixer]: 2019-08-12T15:58:21.798783Z  info    Built new config.Snapshot: id='9'
istio-system/istio-policy-7f86484668-fc8lv[mixer]: 2019-08-12T15:58:21.798819Z  error   2 errors occurred:
istio-system/istio-policy-7f86484668-fc8lv[mixer]:      * action='authz-rule.rule.istio-demo[0]': Handler not found: handler='opa-handler.opa.istio-demo'
istio-system/istio-policy-7f86484668-fc8lv[mixer]:      * rule=authz-rule.rule.istio-demo: No valid actions found in rule
```

I've tried to apply it in the `istio-system` namespace, but same issue.

Anyone can help out here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can try out the [OPA/Istio/Envoy integration](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa-istio-plugin) that enforces the same type of policies at the proxy layer

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work with Istio 1.4 installed with demo profile.
It was also necessary to enable policies check by running:

`istioctl manifest apply --set values.global.disablePolicyChecks=false --set values.pilot.policy.enabled=true`

Find `handler`, `authorization template` and `rule` configuration below

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: handler
metadata:
  name: opa-handler
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  compiledAdapter: opa
  params:
    policy:
      - |+
        package mixerauthz
        default allow = false
    checkMethod: "data.mixerauthz.allow"
    failClose: true

---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: instance
metadata:
  name: authz-instance
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  compiledTemplate: authorization
  params:
    subject:
      user: source.uid | ""
    action:
      namespace: destination.namespace | "default"
      service: destination.service.host | ""
      path: request.path | ""
      method: request.method | ""

---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
 name: auth
 namespace: istio-system
spec:
 actions:
 - handler: opa-handler.handler.istio-system
   instances:
   - authz-instance.instance.istio-system
```

Then I got 403 with this message in my web service (httpbin)

```
PERMISSION_DENIED:opa-handler.istio-system:opa: request was rejected, opa-handler.istio-system:opa: request was rejected
```